# Return redirect in returning NoneType instead of REDIRECTING - Python Django [ERROR]

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Here I wan't to redirect the if sessions don't exist. But the function `authenticate` is returning None instead of rediecting to homepage. WHat's the solution...

inside authenticate function:

```
def authenticate(request):
    username = request.session.get('username')
    password = request.session.get('password')
    email = request.session.get('email')
    if username and password:
        user_data = User.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
        if user_data.is_active:
            return {'bool':True, 'ud':user_data}
        elif not user_data.is_active and username:
            redirect(f'verify/{username}')
        else:
            return False
    else:
        request.session.delete()
        return redirect('/')
```

inside `views.py`

```
def profile(request, username):
    auth = authenticate(request)
```

But, it is working for:

```
def profile(request, username):
    auth = authenticate(request)
    if not auth:
        return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.It will return None because in the  authenticate function you are redirecting to='/' not returning.so it will return None

Comment: Nope bro. If I use it like: `return redirect('homepage')` the same issue is popping op. Also for you info, `return redirect('/')` will also redirect us to basepage.

Comment: It is also working for. Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that the `profile` view does not return anything. In Django, [a view function should return a response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/#writing-views).

My suggestion is you could return a value from the `authenticate` function, evaluate that value in the `profile` view, and redirect/render as necessary from there.

Comment: I know that I can do that, but I am using that authentication function is various places and I don't want to write the same if/esle everywhere..